# Are Iterators right hand value assignment operations atomic?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, parallel-processing

I'm currently dealing with a data race somewhere in my code and can't really seem to pinpoint where exactly this is occurring. What I mean by right hand assignment is

```
Iterator iter = destination; //assign local iterator from dest iterator
```

for context, the function splits up a data set into chunks and executes each chunk in parallel. Each chunk will execute a lambda function, and the chunks are not guaranteed to execute in any order. They may all be ran at the same time or some before others. The beginning of the lambda has the line above, so:

```
[dest](Data &data, Iterator part_begin, std::size_t part_size) mutable
{
    Iterator iter = dest;
    std::advance(iter, get<0>(data)); //use this iter for the algorithm
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

Is this a safe operation to do? I know iterators value accessing is not an atomic operation such as `int` is, so I'm uncertain if this is valid.

Comment: The rules for iterators are the same as for any other type. Multiple concurrent reads are ok but a concurrent write and read is a race condition/UB.

Comment: @bamboon dont concurrent reads of a dereferenced pointer also cause a race condition?

Comment: No, not if there also no writes to the dereferenced object.

Comment: You don't appear to be modifying the sequence that iterator is based on, right? example of modifying the sequence would be a vector that has your `//....` unspeakable code inserting, erasing, etc, about the given iterator. `dest` is being captured in that lambda by value btw, so there is more reading and assigning/copying of that iterator than you may think.

Comment: BTW, your "assignment" is in fact initialization. Assignment requires a pre-existing object. In a definition `T t = expr` the new object `t` is initialized by a constructor that takes `expr`